# Python Selenium Exception

Tags: python, selenium, exception

can you help me with the code, because i don't know how to handle this problem. So I want to automate one task on some website. The BOT I'm making should perform couple of clicks. The problem is that some of the links are on the next page, and i'm getting NoSuchElementException. I closed my code in TRY EXCEPT but i have no idea how to make the program go further and not to stop after handling the exception.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import os


class Bot:
    def __init__(self,username,pw):

        #os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get("https://app.fakturownia.pl/login")
        sleep(1)

        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='user_session[login]']").send_keys(username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='user_session[password]']").send_keys(pw)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='commit']").click()

        sleep(1)
        self.driver.get("url")
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[1]").click()

    def fakturuj(self):
        try:
            for faktura in range(2,28):
                #nr fv
                self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('{}/06/2021'.format(faktura + 1)).click()
                #edytuj 1
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pad-wrapper"]/div[4]/div/nav/div[2]/ul[2]/li[3]/a/span').click()
                #edytuj 2
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="seller_text"]/label/span').click()
                #odśwież nr konta
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="update_seller_bank_account_button"]').click()
                #zapisz
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="invoice_submit_button1"]').click()
                #
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pad-wrapper"]/div[4]/div/nav/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/a').click()

        except NoSuchElementException:

#this clicks on the next page button to find the missing element but idk how to make it go back to the loop
            
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "/html/body/form/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[1]").click()
            


bot = Bot('mail', 'passw')
bot.fakturuj()
```

Answer (score 0):

The NoSuchElementException is an indicator that one of the elements that you are trying to access in the `xpath` or `link_text` part.

You may have possibly misspelled the element or mistyped it... My advice would be to double/triple check the elements (`xpath` or `link_text` methods).

Have a nice day, and let me know if it worked!

Comment: it finds it, but idk if i said all right. I meant that: looking for the link to click-> no link (throws exception)->  handle it by clicking next page (and here program ends, but i would like it to go back to loop)->go back to loop and continue till the end

Comment: Maybe this way: 
if Exception: self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "/html/body/form/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[1]").click()